# Directory path in environment variable as argument to CMD command DIR

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables, console

How can a [Windows/CMD environment variable](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) be used as argument to [CMD's builtin dir command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)?

```
>echo %pythonpath%
C:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts\

>dir %pythonpath%
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is because its value contains space.

The interpreter, that is Command Prompt treats space as separator between commands.

Separators are one of several **special characters** for the interpreter (`cmd.exe`).

Double quoting spaces is called *escaping* special characters.

Another way to escape a special character is using the caret `^` in front of it, that is prepending (ie prefixing) caret to the special character.

For example, you can achieve the same by issuing:

```
dir C:\Program^ Files\Python35\Scripts\
```

Note the caret after "Program"

To contrast and clarify, the greater-than character `>` is also a special character for Command Prompt. It is a special character because it has a special function of *redirecting output*, that is it works as a command of its own despite being just a single character.

So it should also be escaped.

For example you can set your prompt to appear as an indicative arrow by properly escaping it:

```
prompt ^>
```

Would result on:

[image: Example screenshot to illustrate Special Character Escaping]

So it is a good practice to always double quote the argument, that is the value of variable, meaning `"%Variable%"` so the interpreter *never* expects a confusion in that context.

Answer (score 0):

The argument needs to be enclosed in double quotes as the path in question contains a space:

```
>dir "%pythonpath%"
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-ABCD

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts

09.10.2016  08:13    <DIR>          .
09.10.2016  08:13    <DIR>          ..
23.09.2016  14:59            98.145 autopep8.exe
...
```